# GTM: gtm.linkClick only firing when CMD clicking

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, event-propagation

I have a GTM "Just Links" trigger designed to track a simple `a` element, but no `gtm.linkClick` event appears.

Oddly, it DOES work fine if I hold down CMD while clicking the link (triggering the opening of a new window), even though the link in question is to a fragment identifier (#).

[image]

There's JS on the page that I didn't write. Could this be the culprit behind this odd behaviour? If not, what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You might have the checkbox set at the "validate link" option. As far as GTM is concerned, hrefs that start with a fragment identifier are not valid links, so you need to uncheck that.

Comment: Good shout, but both Wait for Tags and Check Validation are unchecked!

Comment: There's Javascript that I didn't write elsewhere on the page. Could this be interfering? Like say if it has `return false` somewhere when it handles an element with an `a` element?

Comment: Sure. GTM does not catch the click directly on the link element, it waits for events to bubble up to the document root. Anything that prevents event bubbling will stop GTM event handlers from working.

Comment: Weirdly, I've just discovered that it works if I hold down CMD when I click the link.